# How to upload a file to a folder location on server2, Having php script on server1

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, ftp, image-uploading

I am having a php enabled server1. I have a php code for file upload. But i need the file to be saved on server2.

I have FTP access to server2.

While searching i found this code,

```
    <?php
$ftp_server = "199.53.23.1";
$ftp_user_name = "xxxx";
$ftp_user_pass = "**********";
$remote_dir = "http://server2/Images/";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

//default values
$file_url = "";

if($login_result) {
//set passive mode enabled
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"];
$remote_file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];

$ret = ftp_nb_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);
while(FTP_MOREDATA == $ret) {
$ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);
}

if($ret == FTP_FINISHED) {
echo "File '" . $remote_file . "' uploaded successfully.";
} else {
echo "Failed uploading file '" . $remote_file . "'.";
}
} else {
echo "Cannot connect to FTP server at " . $ftp_server;
}
?>
```

It said unable to connect to Server.

Anyone have an idea on this type of requirement?

Please help.

**UPDATE**

> Server2 doesn't support PHP

Comment: First, go to 1st server and try to connect server 2 through FTP on command line. There may no ftp connection

Answer (score 2):

Here your line

```
$login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
```

Remove @

```
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
```

For SFTP

```
$conn_id = ssh2_connect($ftp_server, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($conn_id);
```

Uses example: `$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", 'r');`

*send a file

```
ssh2_scp_send($conn_id, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);
```

*fetch file

```
ssh2_scp_recv($conn_id, '/remote/filename', '/local/filename');
```

*Create a new folder

```
ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, '/home/username/newdir');
```

*Rename the folder

```
ssh2_sftp_rename($sftp, '/home/username/newdir', '/home/username/newnamedir');
```

*Remove the new folder

```
ssh2_sftp_rmdir($sftp, '/home/username/newnamedir');
```

*Create a symbolic link

```
ssh2_sftp_symlink($sftp, '/home/username/myfile', '/var/www/myfile');
```

*Remove a file

```
ssh2_sftp_unlink($sftp, '/home/username/myfile');
```

Comment: Thank you, But Same problem. It says "Cannot connect to FTP server at IP address"

Comment: have you created the ftp server on 2nd PC? You must have to have that too!
ftp_connect(host,port,timeout);
port is normally 21

Comment: 2nd PC? Sorry i dint get you?

Comment: Sorry, I meant server 2!

Comment: Yes, i have the ftp setup with SFTP and port 22

Comment: Updated the answer! Check out!

Comment: Ya i will check them, Thank you so much for taking some time to help. Great.